# How to classification Text using logistic regression?

Tags: python

I am new in the field of machine learning and i'm looking forward how to make text classification using logistic regression algorithm . I took training and testing sets. My training set consists of 200 text files.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. If you show us the code, we can help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good start on using logistics regression in text classification. Both are doing classification based on documents and using logistics regression on prediction.  goodluck!

```
https://gallery.azure.ai/Experiment/Logistic-Regression-for-Text-Classification-Sentiment-Analysis-1

https://de.dariah.eu/tatom/classification_logistic_regression.html
```